# Find number of inversions in a given array

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

Can you please give me a hint on how to improve performance of the following algorithm meant to find the number of inversions in a given array?

```
/* *
 * INPUT:
 * 1. t : number of test cases; t test cases follow
 * 2. n : number of elements to consider in each test case
 * 3. ar[i] : n numbers, elements of considered array
 * */

import java.util.*;

public class Inversions1 {

    public static long[] ar;
    public static long[] buff;

    // Merges arrays left[] and right[] into ar[], returns number of
    // inversions found in the process
    public static long merge(int low, int middle, int high) {
        int i = low;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = low;
        long count = 0;

        for(int l = low; l <= high; l++) {
                buff[l] = ar[l];
        }

        while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
            if (buff[i] <= buff[j]) {
                ar[k] = buff[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                ar[k] = buff[j];
                j++;
                count += middle-i+1;
            }
                k++;
        }

        while (i <= middle) {
            ar[k] = buff[i];
            i++; k++;
        }
        while(j <= high) {
            ar[k] = buff[j];
            j++; k++; 
        }
        return count;
    }

    // Traditional merge sort on arr[], returns number of inversions
    public static long invCount(int low, int high) {
        if(low < high) {

            int middle = low + (high - low)/2;

            return invCount(low, middle) + invCount(middle+1,high) + merge(low, middle, high);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int t, n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = sc.nextInt();
        while(t-- > 0) {
            n = sc.nextInt();
            ar = new long[n];
            buff = new long[n];
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                ar[i] = sc.nextLong();
            }
            System.out.println(invCount(0,n-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant to performance, but I'd suggest to get rid of this `static` everywhere. Create a class encapsulation the data and let it do its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two things that can speed up your code:

1. Using custom scanner instead of `java.util.Scanner`. You can create it using `BufferedReader` and `StringTokenizer`. It speeds up input significantly.
2. Avoiding allocation of `left` and `right` arrays inside `invCount` functions. To do it, you can rewrite your `merge` and `invCount` function so that they always use your initial array and take lower and upper bound indices. Merging would require additional buffer anyway, but it can be allocated only once (before  any `merge` is executed). So there would be only two array allocations per test case. It would probably make you code slightly longer and less readable, but it should make it faster.

Comment: I did as you say, but the output is not correct any more, generally lower. Do you [see](http://tny.cz/b44a1e45) what is wrong?

Comment: @mirgee In `invCount`, you merge from `buff` into `ar`, and on the next invocation again.... `ar` gets never used, strange recursion, isn't it?

Comment: @maaartinus It does get used. I save a copy of both merged parts of 'arr' into 'buff' and merge them right into 'arr' again, as user2040251 advised. That works fine, the array is still gets sorted (try to run [this](http://tny.cz/01515df2), please). But I must be counting the inversions wrong. I fail to see how!

Comment: @mirgee For the input `5 1 6 2 7 0` I get `0 6 1 0 7`. No idea, what it means, just write a proper automated test showing that the sorting works. It's surely easier than writing some input manually twice or more.

Comment: @maaartinus I have put a new, working version of the code in the original post, tweaked as advised by user2040251. It is still too slow though.

Comment: @mirgee 1)You are still using standard Scanner. 2)What level of performance improvement are you trying to achieve(how much do you need to speed it up)?

Comment: @user2040251 I need it to run under 5s with arrays of size 200000 elements storing integers <= 10^7 on Intel Pentium III 733 MHz and 256MB of memory.

Comment: @mirgee You should definitely use a custom scanner. java.util.Scanner is too slow.

Comment: @mirgee Or just completely rewrite it in C++.

Comment: @user2040251 Could you please give me a hint on how to use it? I looked hard and found no tutorial...

Comment: @mirgee You can create something like new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)), use readLine() method to read input line by line and then utilize StringTokenizer to split a line into tokens and finally convert each token to int.